# Switch branch and ignore any changes without committing

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout

I was working on a git branch and was ready to commit my changes, so I made a commit with a useful commit message. I then absentmindedly made minor changes to the code that are not worth keeping. I now want to change branches, but git gives me,

> error: You have local changes to "X"; cannot switch branches.

Can I change branches without committing? If so, how can I set this up? If not, how do I get out of this problem? I want to ignore the minor changes without committing and just change branches.

Comment: I believe this only happens when they changes are staged for commit but not commited? git checkout works just fine for changing branches if you haven't staged the files yet using git add or the like.

Comment: Hi Jeremy,

What do you mean by 'staged'? 

Forcing the user to commit file before changes branches doesn't seems like a great workflow. For example, if I'm in the master repository and quickly want to check something in a branch. I have to commit the code to the master first, even it the code is half written! 

Are you saying that indeed, it should be possible to checkout a branch in this situation?

Comment: @boyfarrell You can use 'Git stash' to temporarily save the changes without committing.

Comment: Cross-linking the closely related [How do I force “git pull” to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files)

Comment: when you switch to a branch without committing changes in the old branch, git tries to merge the changes to the files in the new branch. If merging is done without any conflict, swithing branches will be successful and you can see the changes in the new branch. But if a conflict occur, you will get `error: You have local changes to '<filename>'; cannot switch branches.` and branch will not change. you can do `git checkout -m <branch-name>` to merge conflicts and checkout to the branch and resolve conflicts yourself, or `git checkout -f <branch-name>` to ignore changes.

Comment: `git stash save`
`git checkout branch`
// do something
`git checkout oldbranch`
`git stash pop`

Answer (score 526, accepted):

You need a clean state to change branches. The branch checkout will only be allowed if it does not affect the 'dirty files' (as [Charles Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19563/charles-bailey) remarks in the comments).

Otherwise, you should either:

- [stash](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) your current change or
- [`reset --hard HEAD`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)  (if you do not mind losing those minor changes) or
- [`checkout -f`](https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/Documentation/git-checkout.txt) (When switching branches, proceed even if the index or the working tree differs from HEAD. This is used to throw away local changes. )

Or, more recently:

- [With Git 2.23](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) (August 2019) and the [new command `git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch):
  `git switch -f <branch-name>`
  (`-f` is short for `--force`, which is an alias for `--discard-changes`)

> Proceed even if the index or the working tree differs from HEAD.
> Both the index and working tree are restored to match the switching target.

This differs from `git switch -m <branch-name>`, which triggers a three-way merge between the current branch, your working tree contents, and the new branch: you won't lose your work in progress that way.

Comment: "You need a clean state to change branches." is only true if the branch change affects the 'dirty files'.

Comment: For the stash method, I typed "git stash save", "git checkout otherbranch", then finally "git stash pop".

Comment: Currently i don't see this error message, and the changes i made on one branch shows up on the other when i do "git status". has something changed?

Comment: thanks. the checkout -f was what i needed. i did

git reset --hard
git clean -f
git checkout mybranch -f

Comment: Especially usefull if you're stuck on a branch with tons of merge conflicts which makes you unable to checkout a different branch without the -f command.

Comment: Git stash is not branch specific though, if I git stash pop while on another branch, the changes from the previous branch will pop out

Comment: Here is the one great thing Git got totally wrong by violating the basic definition of a branch. Unlike git branch means two totally different workspaces forked from a repository.

Answer (score 158):

If you want to discard the changes,

```
git checkout -- <file>
git checkout branch
```

If you want to keep the changes,

```
git stash save
git checkout branch
git stash pop
```

Comment: Indeed what Romerun says (to be complete): `git stash save` (when in working branchY) then `git checkout branchX` do something `git add/commit -m` etc. `git checkout branchY` and `git stash pop` to get back the stash

Comment: Maybe so. I have a situation though where I want to do what the answer says, if I’m understanding it right: stash changes, switch from Y to X, then pop changes and commit them on X.

Comment: note that `git stash save` is now deprecated in favor of `git stash push`

Comment: [This alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56505204/5353461) simplifies the case of keeping changes when changing branches.

Answer (score 82):

well, it should be

```
git stash save
git checkout branch
// do something
git checkout oldbranch
git stash pop
```

Comment: Yes, stash is global, not branch specific, if I stash pop after switching branch I'll get the same stash as on the other branch(es)

Comment: Should be noted `git stash` will default to `git stash save`

Comment: Thank you , it's very helpful for me

Answer (score 26):

Follow,

```
$: git checkout -f

$: git checkout next_branch
```

Answer (score 20):

Note that if you've merged remote branches or have local commits and want to go back to the remote HEAD you must do:

```
git reset --hard origin/HEAD
```

`HEAD` alone will only refer to the local commit/merge -- several times I have forgotten that when resetting and end up with "your repository is X commits ahead.." when I fully intended to nuke ALL changes/commits and return to the remote branch.

Answer (score 15):

None of these answers helped me because I still had untracked files even after reset and stash. I had to do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git clean -d -f
```

Answer (score 11):

## **git checkout -f your_branch_name**

```
git checkout -f your_branch_name
```

if you have troubles reverting changes:

```
git checkout .
```

if you want to remove untracked directories and files:

```
git clean -fd
```

Answer (score 9):

If you have made changes to files that Git also needs to change when switching branches, it won't let you. To discard working changes, use:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Then, you will be able to switch branches.

Answer (score 8):

Follow these steps:

1. Git stash save will save all your changes even if you switch between branches.

> ```
> git stash save
> ```

2. Git checkout any other branch, now since you saved your changes you can move around any branch. The above command will make sure that your changes are saved.

> ```
> git checkout branch
> ```

3. Now when you come back to the branch use this command to get all your changes back.

> ```
> git stash pop
> ```

Answer (score 6):

### Easy Answer:

is to force checkout a branch

```
git checkout -f <branch_name>
```

Force checking out a branch is telling git to drop all changes you've made in the current branch, and checkout out the desired one.

or in case you're checking out a commit

```
git checkout -f <commit-hash>
```

> "thought that I could change branches without committing. If so, how
>   can I set this up? If not, how do I get out of this problem?"

The answer to that is **No**, that's literally the philosophy of Git that you keep track of all changes, and that each node (i.e. commit) has to be up-to-date with the latest changes you've made, unless you've made a new commit of course.

### You decided to keep changes?

Then stash them using

```
git stash
```

and then to unstash your changes in the desired branch, use

```
git stash apply
```

which will apply you changes but keep them in the stash queue too. If you don't want to keep them in the stash stack, then pop them using

```
git stash pop
```

That's the equivalent of `apply` and then `drop`

Answer (score 5):

switching to a new branch losing changes:

```
git checkout -b YOUR_NEW_BRANCH_NAME --force
```

switching to an existing branch losing changes:

```
git checkout YOUR_BRANCH --force
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the changes and change the branch in a single line command

```
git stash && git checkout <branch_name> && git stash pop
```

Answer (score 3):

For your mental calmness
(to have much easier access to changes you have left uncomitted doing a branch switch)

Before switching:

```
git checkout <next_branch>
```

use

```
git stash save "brief description of changes"
```

instead of the default:

```
git stash    
// or
git stash save
```

This pays off if your `git stash list` is a longer list
and must switch back to some previous idea started somewhere there.

Answer (score 2):

### Move uncommited changes to a new branch

I created a `.gitconfig` alias for this:

```
[alias]
spcosp = !"git stash push && git checkout \"$@\" && git stash pop --index #"
```

To change to `new-branch-name`, use:

```
git spcosp new-branch-name
```

And any non-commited file and index changes will be kept.

Answer (score 2):

To switch to other branch without committing the changes when git stash doesn't work. You can use the below command:

**git checkout -f branch-name**

Answer (score 1):

Close terminal, delete the folder where your project is, then clone again your project and voilá.

Comment: git is not designed to push you to delete the project and clone again! if you want to get the latest version from origin, you just `reset --hard`!

Comment: This solution will do the job, but it's like you want to drive to Boston from New York, but decide to go via Montreal.

Answer (score 0):

[git stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) command is used to save changes that have not been committed to a temporary area so that you can switch to a different branch, make changes, and then come back to your original changes.

```
git stash save "Your stash message"
git checkout <Target branch>
```

// Do your work: change, commit or what your are want

```
git checkout <Current branch>
git stash list
git stash apply stash@{n}
```