# Checking out specific branch from github

Tags: git, git-branch

I used to pull down jQuery-ui by doing

```
git clone git://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/
git checkout 1.8.6
```

This stopped working today.  After I do a git clone on an empty repository, the checkout fails with:

> error: You have local changes to
>   'demos/spinner/currency.html'; cannot
>   switch branches.

Any recommendations on how to fix this?  I don't want to pull zips of 1.8.6, I want the ease of being able to switch between old and new branches of jQuery UI for testing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304626/git-switch-branch-and-ignore-any-changes-without-committing/1304645#1304645 could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have local modifications in your working copy. Thus you can't switch.

Either commit those changes using `git commit` or reset them using `git reset --hard`

Since you are getting this on git clone I suspect this may be related to your core.autocrlf setting.

Try running `git diff` - If you see all lines in the file being marked as changed git is converting the line endings upon checkout.

You can fix this by running

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Retry the clone/checkout after setting core.autocrlf to false. This should have fixed the issue

Hope this helps.

Comment: Bingo that indeed was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you can do:

```
git clone git://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/ -b 1.8.6
```

which would answer the question in the title.

Comment: This is a good shortcut and did work even when my git config was messed up.  However, that's all I can do.  It still wouldn't fix the problem of autocrlf making local changes to files.