# What is the use of "git checkout -f" when "git status" shows tracked file changes on all branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout, git-status

I have a tracked file (an old versioned file) that i modified on master branch.
The staus on master branch shows this file as modified but
The status on the topic branch also shows this file as modified.

Earlier there was an error "error: You have local changes to "X"; cannot switch branches" when i checkout to the other branch without doing a stash or without using "-f" in git-checkout.

i have checked "stackoverflow.com/questions/1304626/git-switch-branch-and-ignore-any-changes-without-committing" but that error doesnt occur and am able to checkout even when i have local changes.

Is there any kind of config that is causing this confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the branch you're switching to is in the same state as the branch you're coming from. Each branch is a pointer on a tree of commits. Therefore, if two branches [point to the same set of commits](http://weenix.cs.brown.edu/mediawiki/index.php/File%3aGit_branch1.png) , you can switch between them without checking in local changes. The reason is that until you actually commit the changes, it does not make a difference to git which branch you commit them to. However, once you have commit the change, then one branch has it and the other one does not and their histories are now different.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you commit, the modified changes are not part of any branch but is applicable to your working directory  and checking out another branch will bring those changes to the other branch as well ( unless there are conflicts)

If you don't want the changes you did while in master to be in other branch when check that out, either commit the changes or stash them.

Comment: Thanks, but earlier there was a message like "error: You have local changes to "X"; cannot switch branches." now this doesn't show up, is there any changes?

Comment: @SenthilAKumar - Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304626/git-switch-branch-and-ignore-any-changes-without-committing

Comment: it says "You need a clean state to change branches (only if the branch change affects the 'dirty files', as Charles Bailey remarks in the comments)"  but even when i have dirty changes i can switch branch without -f option

Comment: That can happen if the branch you're switching to is in exactly the same state as the branch you're switching from. In other words, if the changes on the branch you're switching to are the same as the branch you're switching from, you can switch branches freely. A simple test of this is to create a new branch without switching to it, then change a tracked file. After that, try switching to the new branch. You will be able to.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

on the master

Comment: reset removes the changes on both branches. I want to know why GIT shows the same changes on both branches

Comment: if you run it on master, reset removes uncommitted changes only in master

Comment: if as you said that changes didn't commit to other branch I guess you didn't commit changes in first branch and you just checkout to master without committing