# How to remove the module and directory while checking out different branch

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea

So the problem here is I have my code in `some-git` repository build with `maven` with branches `master` and `myBranch`. The present `master` structure is : 
Project_
        |
        Core
        Driver
        Tests _ XTest
             |_ YTest

And recently I have made changes onto `myBranch` refactoring modules and directories.
Project_
        |
        Core[core]
        Driver[driver]
        XTests[x-test]  // format []
        YTests[y-test]

Using `intelliJ` and currently on `myBranch` as I checkout `master` the entire structure is restored but the directories `XTests` and `YTests` would not be removed. Any ideas onto why this is happening and what's the solution to get this corrected so that the directories are no more there?

Note : Not the entire directory remains but just the resources from XTests and YTests under `/src/main/resources` are still there in the project.

Comment: By 'module', are you referring to a maven module or a git submodule?

Comment: @1615903 : maven module, the format specifies that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to checkout your branch to a different folder than your original work folder, git will not delete the existing folders (from the different folder structure) to this new one - so you would still have folders in Tests\x-test and Tests\y-test.

However, `git clean -fd` could be used to remove untracked directories.

Comment: couldn't get you there,could you exemplify the solution

Comment: What I am trying to say is that git wont delete directories. So when you switch from one branch to another and you expect that directories that used to be in a specific folder, now to be deleted or removed because you changed the structure in another branch, (what you actually did from master to mybranch) it wont happen! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499157/git-checkout-pull-doesnt-remove-directories) for related answers on this specific behavior

Comment: `git clean -fd` does clean the unused directories after checking out a different branch