# Why git is not hiding empty folder in branch change?

Tags: git, android-studio

In git master branch there is one android studio project and in another branch named x, there is sub android studio project. When I go to master from branch x, git show empty folder of subproject. But I want to hide everything of sub project from master. How can I do that?

Added root folder file in git ignore, but still not working. Master show empty subproject folder.

```
/*.iml
/.gradle
/local.properties
/.DS_Store
/build
/captures
/.externalNativeBuild
/.idea
```

in master

[image: Imgur]

**I want in master "RemoteTestApp" folder will be hidden**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git checkout/pull doesn't remove directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499157/git-checkout-pull-doesnt-remove-directories)

Comment: Check to see if Ian MacDonald's comment is the issue. Otherwise, have you tried adding `RemoteTestApp/` to the git ignore?

Comment: Thank you for the replay. my problem was not fixed, maybe because there are empty subfolders.