# git clean not removing sub-directories (not recursive)

Tags: git

I am facing problems with `git clean`.
Consider the following scenario:

```
git status -su
?? file_1
?? xyz/file_2

git clean -f
Not removing xyz/file_2
Removing file_1
```

I don't want to remove the `xyz` folder, but I want to remove the `file_2` inside it.

Why is `git clean` is not working recursively?

Answer (score 54):

If you have it in ignore, use `git clean -xf`. You can do `git clean -xdf` but that will also remove untracked directories. Use `-n` for a dry-run.

http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/16/cleaning-up-untracked-files.html

Comment: Couldn't agree more - git clean -df for the win, awesome -n flag for testing before breaking. :)

Answer (score 17):

Also, git clean doesn't work up the directory tree. Consider you have

```
> git status
Untracked files:
  ../file1.orig
  ../../file2.orig
```

git clean -df would do nothing in this state. You have to 'cd' into the project root and run 'git clean -df' there again.

Comment: Might be nice if it did go up the tree, and everywhere in the tree given that `git status` does that but is possibly by design.

Answer (score 10):

try this:

```
git clean -xdf
```

let me know if that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have the `xyz` directory in your `.gitignore` file somewhere? You can override this behaviour using the `-x` switch to `clean`. Also, if the `xyz` directory is not tracked (has nothing inside it that is tracked), it will not be removed unless you pass the `-d` option.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, on Widows, even a `git clean -xdf` might fail, *silently* skipping a path when it cannot `lstat()` it; now (Git 2.23, Q3 2019), it gives a warning.

See [commit b09364c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b09364c47a015dee7735fd2c038d7d710417c2f2) (18 Jul 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
Helped-by: [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe), [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder), and [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f3d508f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3d508f40e3d85fdbe1dafe8f33782766c88dbdd), 25 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### `clean`: show an error message when the path is too long
>
> When `lstat()` failed, `git clean` would abort without an error message, leaving the user quite puzzled.
>
> In particular on Windows, where the default maximum path length is quite small (yet there are ways to circumvent that limit in many cases), it is very important that users be given an indication why their command failed because of too long paths when it did.
>
> This test case makes sure that a warning is issued that would have helped the user who reported [`git-for-windows/git` issue 521](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/521)
>
> Note that we temporarily set `core.longpaths = false` in the regression test; this ensures forward-compatibility with the `core.longpaths` feature that has not yet been upstreamed from Git for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git clean -di`. It will recurse, show the files, and ask what to do.

Example:

```
$ git clean  -di
Would remove the following items:
  src/main/java/org/jabref/logic/util/comparator/
  src/test/java/org/jabref/logic/util/comparator/
  src/test/resources/org/jabref/logic/quality/
  src/test/resources/org/jabref/logic/search/search/
*** Commands ***
    1: clean                2: filter by pattern    3: select by numbers
    4: ask each             5: quit                 6: help
What now> 1
Removing src/main/java/org/jabref/logic/util/comparator/
Removing src/test/java/org/jabref/logic/util/comparator/
Removing src/test/resources/org/jabref/logic/quality/
Removing src/test/resources/org/jabref/logic/search/search/
```