# Can't get rid of "Changes not staged for commit'

Tags: git

I am unable to get rid of this state in which my repo is seem to be locked in. After a doing a reset to HEAD~1, I keep getting this notification about this single file being modified. 'add' and 'checkout' have not affect. I have core.autocrlf and core.safecrlf unset (empty).

Please see below:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.9.6 (Apple Git-31.1)

$ git status

# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   a_file_name.cpp
```

The followings commands (ran individually) have no affect:

```
$ git checkout -- a_file_name.cpp
$ git reset a_file_name.cpp
$ git add a_file_name.cpp
$ git reset --hard
$ git clean -n
<nothing>
$ git clean -f
<nothing>

$ git status

# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   a_file_name.cpp
```

and it goes on ...

### What did I do wrong?

Response to @Don's suggestion below (git rm), no change, but here is how it goes:

```
$ git rm 
error: 'a_file_name.cpp' has local modifications
(use --cached to keep the file, or -f to force removal)
$ git rm -f a_file_name.cpp
rm 'a_file_name.cpp'
$ git status

# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       deleted:    a_file_name.cpp
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    a_file_name.cpp
#

$ git commit -m"tmp"
[master 2a9e054] tmp
1 file changed, 174 deletions(-)
delete mode 100644 a_file_name.cpp

$ git status
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    a_file_name.cpp
#
```

Pretty much back to sq.1

Comment: What are your line ending settings (`autocrlf`, `safecrlf`, `.gitattributes`, etc.)?

Comment: have you tried just git --stash and just stash all your changes?

Comment: @CynicalOptimist `git stash` has no effect.

Comment: @ellotheth I don't have a .gitattributes. Others settings not present either.

Comment: What happens when you do `git checkout -- a_file_name.cpp`? Also be sure you are in the same directory as the file when you run this.

Comment: I didn't suggest ``git rm``.  I said "delete the unwanted files."  By which I meant, delete it from the file system.  What's your goal here?  Are you trying to add the file to your repository or get rid of it?

Comment: Is `a_file_name.cpp` the actual name of the file that you are having issues with or have you sanitized it for this question?

Comment: @DonBranson My objective is to get rid if this condition and move on. This file was part of the history in the repo and was moved elsewhere. I am in the middle of a rebase operation. However, none of that is important. I should not be stuck in this state and one of the aforementioned commands should be able to get me out. (PS deleting file outside of git results in 2nd half of the state that I just added above, ie `#       deleted:    a_file_name.cpp`

Comment: Ok. @Code-Guru - you got it. File *was* indeed in a sub-directory. Doing git checkout -- within that directory fixed the issue!
(but why?)

Comment: Can you try ``git commit . -m"tmp"`` instead of ``git commit -m"tmp"``

Comment: @CharlesBailey It has been renamed to 'protect the innocent' :)

Comment: When I encountered a similar problem, I was in a subdirectory of my local copy and trying to issue git commands on a file that was in the root directory of the local copy. Obviously `git add filename` is not the same as `git add ../filename`.

Comment: @DonBranson Thanks. The issue has been resolved (disappeared?) after following steps from 'Code-Guru'.

Comment: @FractalSpace: It makes it hard to answer your question if what looks like commands and output are actually faked and missing crucial details.

Comment: How do I mark @Code-Guru 's reply as 'Answer' ?

Comment: @CharlesBailey The commands and output are real. Just file has been renamed. I don't this should affect any answer. However, the problem is solved, so thanks anyway.

Comment: @FractalSpace: In that case, if you weren't in the correct directory, I don't understand why git status didn't give you the correct relative path, e.g. `#       modified:   sub-dir/a_file_name.cpp`. If you can reproduce this then you should log a bug. Git definitely shouldn't do this.

Comment: Unfortunately problem is non-reproducible now. Will watch for it if it repeats because my job is still not done.
Thanks!

Comment: This question remains unanswered -- despite many upvotes. I found answers to other questions more helpful, such as [making sure you are running from the top-level directory within your git project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20838589/1048186)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that you are in the same directory as the file when you run any `git` commands. Alternatively, you can use a relative or absolute path for files used with `git` commands. The output from `git status` *should* indicate the subdirectory where the file is located. I find it strange that the output you posted here doesn't show that.

Comment: I found it more helpful to run the commands not from the same directory, but from the git project's [top-level directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20838589/1048186)

Comment: @JosiahYoder Yes, you can do that as well.

Answer (score 7):

```
git commit -a -m "message"
```

The -a option will add all tracked files with modifications

Answer (score 6):

A round about way that worked for me, is to:

1. recreate the file that I deleted.
2. `git add path/filename`
3. `git rm --cached path/filename`
4. delete the file
5. `git add .`
6. `git commit --amend # if not on an already pushed branch.`

Comment: Yeah this worked for me, made a merge and there was a file with the same name, so one was prefixed with ~HEAD. I deleted it manually and commited the merge. Then there was a phantom file that I could not add nor delete... Also realised the unstaged file had no uppercase but my file on disk had uppercase...

Answer (score 2):

Do you need any of the changes in the modified file?  git-reset by default leaves the files in the directory tree.

```
git reset --hard
```

will reset and write over the files in your working tree with the files in the commit.

Have you done a git diff after each of the steps to see if any changes actually exist?

Comment: git reset --hard 
has no affect. (at this point, I don't need this file)
The diff *does* show some changes.

Comment: You can either delete the unwanted files, or ``git add .`` before ``git reset --hard`` to every untracked file permanently.

Comment: Do you have a permissions issue?  Does the file ever change after any checkout, reset, etc?

Comment: @jeremy git fsck did show some dangling object, did git gc. However, no change.

Comment: @FractalSpace git rm won't help, since it's not a tracked file.

Comment: @DonBranson Permissions were 644. Changed to 755. Same result. git rm has interesting results. I am adding to the original question for clarity but basically the status quo continues.

Answer (score 1):

this could happen if the file in question has a different capitalization.

in my case it was

`README.md`
`readme.md`

git won't let you simple `git add ...` a case change.

you can fix that by doing something like

`git mv -f readme.md README.md`