# Git force overwrite of local tracked files but not local untracked files

Tags: git

I was working in a local directory named `p1` which contains a git repo.  After adding a branch and making a commit on the added branch, I made a copy of the directory `p1` and called it `p2`.  My intention was to play around with merging and rebasing (just to learn) in directory `p2`, while pushing to the remote repo from `p1` when I determined how I wanted to merge/rebase my changes.

However, I accidentally did the merging and then pushed to the remote repo from the `p2` directory.  This is OK, because now the remote repo has the correct state of my git project.

However, I need to now replace what's in directory `p1` with what's in the remote repo.  That way, directory `p1` will be up-to-date.

When I go into directory `p1` and try to pull from the remote repo, here is what I get:

```
git pull
Updating e07d50d..287ec08
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    debug/external/subdir.mk
    debug/makefile
    debug/subdir.mk
    input/parameters.cfg
    main.cpp
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Now, I have found potential solutions to this problem, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/force-git-to-overwrite-local-files-on-pull).

The problem in my case, however, is that **directory `p2` contains untracked files that I do NOT want deleted when I pull from the remote repo**.

So, how can I pull from the remote repo, overwriting my local tracked files, without deleting local untracked files?

---

Note: one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331139/get-git-to-overwrite-local-changes-but-to-keep-untracked-files) seems to be appropriate for me, but I'm not 100% certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
```