# git pull, keep untracked files ignore and overwrite tracked file modified or deleted

Tags: git, production, pull

I would like to do a git pull to the production server but I'm having some issues.

Someone deleted a tracked file on the server and also modified a file on the server.  The server also adds untracked files that it uses for logs and such.

I would like to do a git pull that will override all tracked files and keep untracked files in tact.

Right now when i do a "git pull origin master" I get the following:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
>       free_profile.php

I've found this on stack overflow:
[Git force overwrite of local tracked files but not local untracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638541/git-force-overwrite-of-local-tracked-files-but-not-local-untracked-files)

But I'm not sure if this is the appropriate solution.  It's a production server so I need to make sure I'm doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean someone deleted a file, but not yet committed, and you want to retrieve it?

If so, please try to use

`git checkout -- your_deleted_file`

Comment: Someone deleted a file from the server that was not supposed to be deleted.  And also modified a file directly on the server instead of doing it through the repository.
The repository is the correct one and I'd like to do a git pull to retrieve the correct files.  But there are also untracked files on the server that I would like to keep.  When I do a git pull it gives me an issue with the file that was edited directly on the server

Comment: Where did you run `git pull` command, on the server? Was modifications committed? if not, you can use `git checkout -- .` to discard all the changes and keep the untracked files.

Comment: What?  Impossible.  How can git checkout a file that's never been tracked??  ` did not match any file(s) known to git`