# How do I overwrite changes on my local copy

Tags: git

I ran `git pull origin master` and I get the following message because I have my changes in a single file. What command should I issue so that the changes are overwritten on my local copies.

- branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
  Updating 7sc4344..c81c437
  error: Your local changes to 'foo.txt' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.
  Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try checking out the file so that your changes are removed with `git checkout -- foo.txt` and then you'll no longer have changes so the merge should go through.

To change everything back to normal, do `git reset --hard HEAD`

Comment: I have many such files in several other directories, is there a command to overwrite all such changes.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this: [How do I force "git pull" to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/force-git-to-overwrite-local-files-on-pull)

```
git clean
git pull
```