# How do I force git pull to overwrite everything on every pull?

Tags: git, git-pull

I have a CENTRAL bare repository that has three developer repositories pulling and pushing to it normally.

I also have two other repositories that pull from the CENTRAL bare repo: one is the live server, and the other is a test/stage server—each pulling from its own respective branch.

The scenario is this: I have a `post-update` hook script on the CENTRAL repo that automatically accesses the test and live repos and runs a pull command on each. This updates both test and live servers, all depending on what branch has new commits. This all works great.

The problem is this: there may be times in an emergency that files may be directly updated on the server (via ftp or whatever) and the CENTRAL post-update script will then fail since merge/overwrite conflicts will occur. There is no way to avoid this scenario, and it is inevitable.

What I would like to have happen is this: I want the pull from the live and test sites to *always* overwrite/merge on pull. ***Always.*** These repos will be pull-only as they are not for development.

In all my research, I cannot find a good solution to have a pull *always* force an overwrite of the local files. Is this at all possible? It would make for a great development scenario if so.

Comment: While I've voted for the 'reset to what you just fetched' answer below, I think the solution to your real problem is to not make out-of-band changes. Modifications, no matter how urgent, should *always* go through version control. No one except operators should have direct access to the running sites (e.g. not developers). Using version control consistently means that you have a record of when changes were made, and who made them, and better tools to work with them. Why subvert it, for no real benefit?

Comment: @Novelocrat right, i understand what you are saying. Unfortunately, there are a number of scenarios where someone could upload a file directly to the server. In that case i would need to run a number of commands to re-sync the repos. Previously we used an FTP script to move files from the repo to the server. The proposed method above would simply eliminate the FTP step, which has worked very well in the past.

Comment: So, don't let people access the server directly. Lock out FTP and SSH access, or tell them they'll be fired for making unaccountable changes. Letting that kind of practice continue only hurts you and your team in the long run.

Answer (score 581, accepted):

Really the ideal way to do this is to not use `pull` at all, but instead `fetch` and `reset`:

```
git fetch origin master
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
git clean -df
```

(Altering `master` to whatever branch you want to be following.)

`pull` is designed around merging changes together in some way, whereas `reset` is designed around simply making your local copy match a specific commit.

You may want to consider slightly different options to `clean` depending on your system's needs.

Comment: @user730569 `reset --hard` is a command which is used to force the state of the working directory (and the current branch) to a state matching that of a particular commit.

Comment: @Amber right, i've used `reset --hard` before, but never in conjunction with `fetch`. When you call fetch, is it merging the contents into master, or into `FETCH_HEAD`. What is `FETCH_HEAD` and where is it relative to master? Lastly what is `clean -df`?

Comment: `FETCH_HEAD` is a reference that is automatically created by `fetch` to represent the fetched ref. It's not merged, just straight-up overwritten whenever you do a fetch. `clean` is a command that removes files which are not tracked by `git`, the `-df` flags tell it to remove directories (`-d`) and actually do the removal (`-f`).

Comment: You might want to use `git clean -dn` before using `git clean -df` so you will see what files/folders will get deleted. `git clean -df` can only be reversed if you had a backup

Comment: amazing!! :-) Thanks Amber.

I would though echo the "git clean -dn" before -df. We have a lot of files that are gitignored but are relevant for the local dev to work so that could've been frustrating loosing those.

Comment: @NickMiddleweek This answer was written in the context of the question, which was as a post-update hook - in other words, no human in the loop, so no-op dryruns are pointless. If doing this on a local repo, sure.

Comment: @NickMiddleweek I was worried `git clean -df` will remove gitignored files too, but turns out it won't. `git clean --help` says "Normally, only files unknown to Git are removed, but if the -x option is specified, ignored files are also removed. This can, for example, be useful to remove all build products."

Comment: This solution worked when I reverted commit remotely while the client had some local commit.

Answer (score 23):

You could try this:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git pull
```

(from [How do I force "git pull" to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/force-git-to-overwrite-local-files-on-pull))

Another idea would be to delete the entire git and make a new clone.

Answer (score 14):

To pull a copy of the branch and **force overwrite of local files** from the origin use:

```
git reset --hard origin/current_branch
```

All current work will be lost and it will then be the same as the origin branch

Answer (score 12):

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/your_branch
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure how to do it in one command but you could do something like:

```
git reset --hard
git pull
```

or even

```
git stash
git pull
```

Comment: To run in one command: `git reset --hard && git pull`. Alternatively, but not better, `git reset --hard; git pull`. Using `&&` will only run the second command if the first command was succesful. `;` will run it regardless of exit code of the first command.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the hook to wipe everything clean.

```
# Danger! Wipes local data!

# Remove all local changes to tracked files
git reset --hard HEAD

# Remove all untracked files and directories
git clean -dfx

git pull ...
```

Comment: what does x do? please explain the switches

Comment: The x is supposed to remove all untracked files, I think.  Hard to tell in manpage-speak, which is why we have SO.

Comment: @JosephK: That's incorrect.  The basic purpose of `git clean` is already "Remove untracked files from the working tree" (top of the page).  Normally, this does not include ignored files, but `-x` tells `git clean` to include ignored files as well (except this does not affect files ignored by the `-e` option).

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't commit the local changes yet since the last pull/clone, you can use:

```
git checkout *
git pull
```

`checkout` will clear your local changes with the last local commit, and
`pull` will sincronize it to the remote repository