# Smartgit not seeing old files added back after reset

Tags: git, smartgit

Yesterday i did some deleting and removed too much (ye i know typical case).
Upon reading blogs about smartgit i resetted to the revision where i left off before all the deletes.
I got my old files back but git does not detect them being there so i'm unable to push them to my server again. Any ideas? I tried looking in gitignore file and in the excludes in the info folder but nothing is there -edit- i already tried a force push.

The steps I used are

```
- Going to logs
- Select the revision
- Press ctr+R (reset)
- Selected hard reset and confirmed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to force pulling all the files back to my server, i found a stackoverflow post for this:

[How do I force git pull to overwrite everything on every pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589814/git-force-a-pull-to-overwrite-everything-on-every-pull)

And what i did was:

```
git fetch origin master
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
git clean -df
```

Added the code for future reference

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you had commits:
A->B->C->D
The D commit was the one where you deleted too much. So you checked out C again. Of course, git detects the files, but since there aren't changed since C which you're looking at, git status won't show you anything.

A push will fail since you're trying to rewrite history of the remote, you need to do a git push -f (that's -f for --force see https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html )

Comment: i already tried the force push with no result, sorry shouldve mentioned that

Comment: There's the possibility that force push is not allowed to your server since it's really bad taste to do that on a public repo

Comment: well fetch fixed my problem, answer below... ty!

Comment: Glad it worked for you, but that doesn't solve the problem you described at all. You just set your branch to the servers master branch and deleted all your local changes.