# Git pull --rebase generating a conflict loop

Tags: git

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but here's what's happening.

My team has a **develop** branch from which we branch to create **feature** branches.

I'm working on one feature and every time I try to pull --rebase from develop I'm met with a bunch of conflicts.

I solve all conflicts and try to push to feature. A message says the tip of my branch is behind feature's and that I should pull from it.

```
  hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
    hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
    hint: before pushing again.
```

I pull from it (without rebasing) and am met with MORE conflicts, which I solve.

Now I can push to feature.

At this point it's all synced and working fine. But if I work on some local work and try pull --rebase from develop, I'm met with a ton of conflicts AGAIN, including some I've already solved (I do have rerere on).

Anything I'm messing up here?

Comment: If you can show us the real Git commands and messages this would be easier to answer. In particular the "*message says my pointer is behind feature's and that I should pull from it*", I believe that's the misstep.

Comment: @Schwern you were right. Updated it with the proper message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you rebase a branch on another branch, you generally *rewrite* the history of that branch.  As a result, a normal push will fail because Git will think that your branch has diverged from what is on the remote.  Instead of doing this:

```
git push origin feature
```

you should have done this:

```
git push --force origin feature
```

There are potentially bad side effects from a force push, *but* if you are the only one working on this feature branch then it is OK.

In terms of a diagram, to better understand what is happening here consider the following:

```
develop: ... A -- B
              \
feature:        C
```

Since you branched `feature` from `develop` you have added a new `C` commit.  Also, someone else (perhaps you as well) has added a `B` commit to `develop`.  Now, you rebase `feature` on `develop`:

```
develop: ... A -- B
                   \
feature              C'
```

Compare the new `feature` against the one before you rebased.  Your new `C'` commit now sits on top of a new base, the `B` commit, and when you go to push, Git will reject it.   Git will see the common `A` commit ancestor, but it won't know how to apply the new commit, not without a merge, which would defeat the point of a rebase.

Comment: What about having to solve all conflicts again when rebasing from develop?

Comment: @Souljacker Not sure what you are asking.  Once you resolve the conflicts in the rebase, you force push `feature` and you are done, there are no more conflicts.

Comment: That's what I thought, but if I edit something and try to rebase from develop, I meet conflicts again. I didn't try with --force, though. Will try and report back

Comment: Ok, force pushing worked! One think, which would be the solution if I had more people working on this branch?

Comment: @Souljacker You may simply have everyone else sharing the branch fetch and then reset their branch to whatever rebased version came in (see [the accpeted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589814/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-everything-on-every-pull)).  Basically, they have to force update their local branches.  Or, they could just delete their local branches, fetch, and checkout fresh copies.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to piece together the commands.

- `git checkout feature`
- `git pull --rebase origin develop`
- fix conflicts, finish rebase
- `git push`

At this point you get something like this.

```
To github.com:org/repo.git
 ! [rejected]        feature -> feature (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:org/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

***The hint is wrong***, a `git pull` here is the wrong thing. ***Instead you should `git push --force`*** to overwrite the upstream `feature` with your own. This is because you've rewritten the `feature` branch and it has *diverged* with the upstream one.

Here's what's happened in more detail. At the start things looked something like this. Note that the upstream `origin/feature` and your local `feature` are at the same commit.

```
                      [origin/develop]
A - B - C - D - E - F [develop]
            \
             G - H - I [feature]
                       [origin/feature]
```

After `git pull --rebase origin develop` and all the conflicts were fixed, your repository looked like this.

```
                    [origin/develop]
                    [develop]
A - B - C - D - E - F - G1 - H1 - I1 [feature]
            \
             G - H - I [origin/feature]
```

`rebase` doesn't rewrite commits. It creates new ones and pretends it was that way all along. Now `feature` and `origin/feature` have *diverged* meaning one is not an ancestor with the other.

When you try to `git push` your `feature` Git refuses. It's not a simple matter of moving `origin/feature` along a few commits, called a "fast-forward". A merge would be required and `git push` won't do that for safety reasons. Your work appears to have *diverged* from everyone else's. A `push` risks blowing over other people's work on the same branch.

That's why the `git push --force` is necessary. It tells Git to do it anyway, put `origin/feature` at commit `I1`. After the `git push --force` you'll have this.

```
                    [origin/develop]
                    [develop]
A - B - C - D - E - F - G1 - H1 - I1 [feature]
            \                        [origin/feature]
             G - H - I
```

Now it's all good. Your `feature` work is as if it was on top of `develop` all along.

If you `git pull --rebase origin develop` again, and there's no new commits on `develop`, nothing should happen. If there are new commits, you'll only have to deal with those.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yup, we're both explaining how Git works.