# git did not pull my remote file and says Already up-to-date

Tags: git, github

I have pushed a last version of project to Git.

And I would like to make an experiment: I change a file development.rb.

And I run **git pull** I expect that my local file development.rb will be replaced by remote file development.rb. But it doesn't. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force git to overwrite local files on pull](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/force-git-to-overwrite-local-files-on-pull)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how git works. If you do:

```
git status
```

You'll see that you have a pending local change.

You can throw away this change and revert to the last commit with:

```
git checkout -- development.rb
```

Comment: This is correct. "git pull" will pull any remote changes into your local repository, but will not affect your current working directory. Since no changes were made to the remote repository since you pushed, your local repository really is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

you should `git checkout development.rb` first, or the `git pull` will try to merge remote changes with your local changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your HEAD is either at the same point of ahead of what is on the remote branch.  I assume your development.rb file has not been committed locally, so you can:

```
git checkout HEAD development.rb
```

To remove local changes to development.rb.