# Git command to checkout any branch and overwrite local changes

Tags: git, deployment, git-checkout

Is there a Git command (or a short sequence of commands) that will safely and surely do the following?

- Get rid of any local changes.
- Fetch the given branch from origin if necessary
- Checkout the given branch?

Currently I'm stuck with:

```
git fetch -p
git stash
git stash drop
git checkout $branch
git pull
```

but it's bothering me because I'm asked for password two times (by `fetch` and `pull`). **Generally I would be happy with any solution as long as the password is needed only once.**

A couple of notes:

- It's a part of homebrewed deployment script for an application (the code is hosted on GitHub).
- There should be no difference if the branch was already fetched from origin or not (i.e. the first deployment of a new branch shouldn't ideally require any additional steps).
- The script is located on a remote machine that can be accessed by several people, hence no credentials are stored and user/password must be entered (but only once if possible).
- I don't care about any local changes; I always want a pristine copy of the given branch (the further part of deployment script produces local changes).
- I can't clone or export a fresh repository each time; it takes too much time.

Comment: 1. `git reset --hard` 2. `git checkout $branch` 3. `git pull origin $branch`

Comment: FYI if you use ssh keys you won't ever be prompted for a password.

Comment: @Slam not if you're using GitLab.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You could follow a solution similar to *"[How do I force “git pull” to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888015/6309)"*:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/abranch
git checkout abranch
```

That would involve only one fetch.

With Git 2.23+, `git checkout` is replaced here with [`git switch` (presented here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) (still experimental).

```
git switch -f $branch
```

(with [`-f` being an alias for `--discard-changes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt--f), as noted in [Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3620376/jan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59951106/6309))

> Proceed even if the index or the working tree differs from HEAD.
> Both the index and working tree are restored to match the switching target.

---

If you do *not* want to *switch* branch, but only *restore* a folder from another branch, then [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) is the other command which replaces the old obsolete and confusing `git checkout`.
I presented [`git restore` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309).

```
git restore --source=anotherBranch --staged] [--worktree -- aFolder
# or, shorter:
git restore -s anotherBranch -SW -- aFolder
```

Comment: I'm using this solution, but I added additional `git checkout $branch` at the end, because otherwise the current branch information returned by git was wrong.

Comment: @VonC, Thank you. this really has overwritten master with branch.

Comment: what if I'm using it to import an entire folder from another branch, and I want their files to overwrite mines? `git checkout ??? develop -- src/main/ `

Comment: @tuxErrante So you don't want to switch branch then? In that case, [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) is for you. Nobody should use in 2021 `git checkout`. It is old, obsolete and confusing. `git restore -s experiment -SW -- aFolder`: that will restore `aFolder` content from the branch `experiment`, both working tree (W) and index (S).

Comment: @tuxErrante I have edited the answer to make the distinction (between switching branch and restoring content) clearer.

Comment: I was having some strange behavior where I couldnt switch from one branch to the next because it would overwrite the files, but I had already committed and pushed those files and merged them on github. So what i did was use the `git switch -f $branch` which worked for me while the first one didnt. Then when it switched to the branch, I did `git pull origin $branch` to pull down the changes, then I did `git reset --hard` and then everything was back to normal thank you

Comment: It is not clear how `origin/abranch` and `$branch` are related. Do you mind elaborating, please?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel That seems to be a typo. I have edited the answer to use the same name as the fetched branch.

Comment: @VonC — Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 40):

Couple of points:

- I believe `git stash` + `git stash drop` could be replaced with `git reset --hard`
- ... or, even shorter, add `-f` to `checkout` command:

  ```
  git checkout -f -b $branch
  ```

  That will discard any local changes, just as if `git reset --hard` was used prior to checkout.

As for the main question:
instead of pulling in the last step, you could just merge the appropriate branch from the remote into your local branch: `git merge $branch origin/$branch`, I believe it does not hit the remote. If that is the case, it removes the need for credensials and hence, addresses your biggest concern.

Comment: The -b may need to be capitalized.  `git checkout -f -B $branch` resets the local branch if it already exists.

Comment: Just `git checkout -B $existing_branch_name` worked for me, whereas `git checkout -f -b $existing_branch_name` didn't – so like @xer0x said, I think the answer is incorrect insofar as the capital `-B` is a requirement?

Answer (score 13):

`git reset` and `git clean` can be overkill in some situations (and be a huge waste of time).

If you simply have a message like "The following untracked files would be overwritten..." and you want the remote/origin/upstream to overwrite those conflicting untracked files, then `git checkout -f <branch>` is the best option.

If you're like me, your other option was to clean and perform a `--hard reset` then recompile your project.

Answer (score 3):

The new [`git-switch` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) (starting in GIT 2.23) also has a flag `--discard-changes` which should help you. `git pull` might be necessary afterwards.

Warning: it's still considered to be experimental.

Comment: Good point. I have promoted git switch in the past (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309). I have updated my 2013 answer to include that new command.