# Git - deploying without clone

Tags: git, deployment

I already have files in project folder on server.
I initialize there git:

```
git init
```

then i set up remote origin

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:xxxx
```

and ssh keys. **Now i want to replace that old files by new files in remote repository. Which command i should use?**

I tried

```
git pull origin master
```

but its not making any changes, and when i making:

```
git checkout master
```

its says:

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten
>   by checkout:
>   I tried that before and it works fine, now i dont have idea what i did wrong)

```
 git checkout .
```

gives error too:

> git checkout .error: pathspec './' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: i dont want to push, its old version on server where i making this commands..

Comment: Looks like you're trying to _force pull_, as described by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/force-git-to-overwrite-local-files-on-pull)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
git fetch
git stash
git checkout -b master origin/master
git stash pop
```

Maybe at this point you can find some conflicts