# Generic git reset to default upstream HEAD

Tags: git, git-reset

Is there a syntax to reset to the current branch's default upstream HEAD?

Something like:

```
git checkout mybranch
git reset --hard origin/mybranch
```

where `origin/mybranch` can be generic for the current branch's upstream HEAD?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntactic magic you want is part of a "revision specifier".  These are documented in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

The string `@{upstream}` (abbreviation, `@{u}`), appended to a branch name, means "resolve the branch to its upstream".  If you omit the branch name, git substitutes in `HEAD`, i.e., `HEAD@{u}`.  This uses `HEAD` to find the current branch and then proceeds as if you had specified that.

So:

```
git reset --hard @{u}
```

will do the job (of course as with any `git reset --hard`, use this with care).

(In some shells you may have to quote the braces.)