# Git override specific (active) branch from remote repository

Tags: git, conflict, pull

I want to override a specific branch that im currently in, in order to override/replace everything from the remote repository server.

If i do `git pull` on that branch i always get a merge conflict because both files are changed, and i cant get it merged right (no mergetool) and i want to avoid any commits that are unneccesary, especially from this server becaue its only a preview server.

I edited the file already and add/ commit the file again, but no success.
So i rolled back with `git reset --hard <sha1>` to the last real commit. 
Hope that wa sok to do so?

Comment: Yes, what you are doing is ok. You can follow this link to understand better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/force-git-to-overwrite-local-files-on-pull

Comment: i tried git fetch --all, now git status tells me im behind 22 commits. But of what 22 commits if i pull everything from remote shouldnt it be up2date?

Comment: You rolled back your local tree, so yea it should say you're behind because the remote tree wasn't rolled back too.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is for fixing a file.

To reset tour branch, you can simply fetch, and reset it to the remote branch:

```
git checkout yourBranch
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/anotherBranch
```

`YourBranch` will now refer to the same commit as `origin/anotherBranch`.
(Depending on what branch you want, `YourBranch` and `origin/anotherBranch` could have the same name)

Make sure you don't have any work in progress (as the reset --hard would delete that)