# Git ignore local file changes

Tags: git

I've tried both

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged config/myconfig
```

and

editing `.git/info/exclude` and adding `config/myconfig`

however when I do git pull I always get:

> Updating 0156abc..1cfd6a5
>   error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
>       config/myconfig
>   Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
>   Aborting

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force Git to overwrite local files on pull](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/force-git-to-overwrite-local-files-on-pull)

Answer (score 140, accepted):

`git pull` wants you to either remove or save your current work so that the merge it triggers doesn't cause conflicts with your uncommitted work. Note that you should only need to remove/save untracked files if the changes you're pulling create files in the same locations as your local uncommitted files.

### Remove your uncommitted changes

#### Tracked files

```
git checkout -f
```

#### Untracked files

```
git clean -fd
```

### Save your changes for later

#### Tracked files

```
git stash
```

#### Tracked files and untracked files

```
git stash -u
```

#### Reapply your latest stash after `git pull`:

```
git stash pop
```

Comment: That last command should be either `git stash apply` or `git stash pop`.  (`pop` is just `apply`-then-`drop`.  I prefer to separate the steps in case of problems, but then again, I prefer to create temporary commits rather than stashing in the first place...)

Comment: Oops, that last one was a mistake, I change it to `git stash pop`. Thanks.

Answer (score 52):

You most likely had the files staged.

```
git add src/file/to/ignore
```

To undo the staged files,

```
git reset HEAD
```

This will unstage the files allowing for the following git command to execute successfully.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged src/file/to/ignore
```

Comment: Hi I did `git update-index --assume-unchanged src/file/to/ignore`, but now I want to track changes on the /file/to/ignore, how can I undo this ?

Comment: git update-index --no-assume-unchanged src/file/to/ignore

Comment: I think skip-worktree is better than unchanged index

Comment: Gits documentation states the solution I provided. Not just based on working experience but, the recommendation by git on the correct course of action.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to do a `git stash` before you `git pull`, this is because it is reading your old config file. So do:

```
git stash
git pull
git commit -am <"say first commit">
git push
```

Also see [git-stash(1) Manual Page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want your local changes, then do below command to ignore(delete permanently) the local changes.

- If its unstaged changes, then do checkout (`git checkout <filename>` or `git checkout -- .`)
- If its staged changes, then first do reset (`git reset <filename>` or `git reset`) and then do checkout (`git checkout <filename>` or `git checkout -- .`)
- If it is untracted files/folders (newly created), then do clean (`git clean -fd`)

If you dont want to loose your local changes, then stash it and do pull or rebase. Later merge your changes from stash.

- Do `git stash`, and then get latest changes from repo `git pull orign master` or `git rebase origin/master`, and then merge your changes from stash `git stash pop stash@{0}`

Comment: how to reverse the effect of `git checkout <filename>`

Comment: This is not what the user asked. This explains how to revert local changes, not how to ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

in Git 2.23 `git restore` is introduced. For detail check [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58003030/what-is-the-git-restore-command-and-what-is-the-difference-between-git-restor#:%7E:text=git%20restore%20is%20introduced%20in,%2Fdocs%2Fgit%2Drestore.) and [www.git-tower.com](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/commands/git-restore).

Here is the commands to discard the local changes and unstage changes:

To discard local tracked changes

`git restore .` or `git restore file1 file2 ...`

To discard local untracked changes

`git clean -fd`

To unstage changes:

`git restore --staged .` or `git restore --staged file1 file2 ...`

Answer (score 0):

When you want to checkout, but incoming changes conflict with local changes, using -f seems to clear only the conflicting files.

```
git checkout -f $branch
```

You switch to the new branch, your local changes are cleared, and your untracked files are kept.