# Git update project from remote repo but keep modified file(s)

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a project with 10 other developers. I clone remote repository. Now, in order to make Docker work, I have to make changes in docker-compose.yml file. But when I want to update my local project (`git pull`) in case project got changed by someone else, it's saying I have to commit changes first. But I don't want to commit the docker-compose.yml file. I want to update the project, but keep changed docker-compose.yml.
Would you please help me how to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24983863/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pull+%22Please%2C+commit+your+changes+or+stash+them%22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stash your local changes, pull the updates and then pop the stashed changes:

```
git stash save
git pull origin
git stash pop
```

Having said that, if it's common for developers to make changes to the `docker-compose.yml` file, you should consider adding it to the `.gitignore` so you don't have to go through this mess each time you pull updates.
One common practice is to ignore `docker-compose.yml` like that, but have a committed `docker-compose.yml.example` file that each developer can copy and modify as needed.