How to ignore file deletion with git in WebStorm
I have a project that has been for over a year in beta. During this time all data folders contained test data. Now it's time for release and the data folders will not come from the project any more.
I would still like to keep those data files in the git project, though, in case I need to work on a new PC or so others can easily start testing the website. But no longer wish Git to track changes to those test files, ignore if there are newer versions on a dev machine.
I've deleted the files locally and WebStorm wants to commit it as seen below.

But I don't want to delete them from git, as I want to ignore them.
Git shouldn't monitor those files any more.
I'm not so sure how to ignore files that are already part of the project. I'd like to keep them in Git, but ignore any future changes to them.

Does this answer your question? How can I make git ignore future revisions to a file?

If you want to keep them but not update them couldn't you just move them to another directory, and "delete" them where they currently are? TemplateTestData/ oldTestData/ whateverYouWantToCallItTestData/. Most of the time this is many times easier to work with than some obscure git setting.

@jonrsharpe Yes i want it like that, thanks .
to Kim currently a script builds it with exclusion of those files.

I think the --assume-unchanged option is what you need. For CLI git, this looks like
git update-index --assume-unchanged src/file/to/ignore

This will have your local machine ignore any changes to these files for commits. But if any of the "ignored" files change in the repo, you will need to revert the local changes before you can pull updates from the repo.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44652029/20331291
