# Git can't pull from origin because of deleted file

Tags: git

I try to pull from origin to update a local git repository, and got the familiar message:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    <list of files>
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Okay, no big deal.  I stashed my changes and pulled again... and got the exact same message.  Okay, that's a bit weird.

So I tried adding and commiting the files... and it still won't pull, for the same reason.

Out of frustration, I deleted the offending file.  And now I *still* get the same error, but the file doesn't even exist anymore.

I'm not entirely sure how to get it to stop tracking a file that doesn't exist... and I'm not sure why I can't pull from source.

git status shows:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 249 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   <list of files>
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does "git status" look like?

Comment: git status shows a list of modified files not staged for commit -- a subset of them responsible for the problem.  See above.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are in a state where you have no uncommitted changes you care about do

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

And from the root of the repository then do

```
git clean -dfx
```

Then try again, and if it doesn't work post a partial of the error and the output of `git status`

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't enable me to pull -- i still have a list of modified / uncommitted files, and i'm back to square one.

Comment: Are you sure that you did not forget "--hard"? That should remove all modifications.

Comment: I am having the same problem as the OP and this does not remove the file.  'git status' still lists it as "modified"

Comment: @KennyPeanuts line ending problem perhaps?

Comment: I don't know what it was doing. Best I could tell the file existed nowhere but git insisted it was modified even after the hard reset. I fixed it with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8888015/686481

Comment: @KennyPeanuts that would have thrown out your local commits on master.  Which certainly could fix this issue but can lose work too

Comment: Yeah, in this case I was lucky that I didn't have any pending commits.  Whatever the issue was I couldn't seem to fix it without that nuclear option.