# Discard all conflict files in source tree or by git

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

How can I discard all conflict files in source tree or git when I try to make pull. Right now I search every file and do it one by one which seems to me little bit hilarious.

Comment: Do you want to keep the files as they are in the working copy, or overwrite them with the newer ones from the repository?

Comment: Overwrite, but only those with conflict.

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/force-git-to-overwrite-local-files-on-pull

Answer (score -1):

Go list of unstaged files , Press Shift button and select the unwanted files you want to discard. And then have right click on them to discard.

hope this was helpful