# git pull issue with untracked files

Tags: git, rename, pull

This is my scenario.

I realised I had a filename in the wrong case on my server. So I changed the filename to the right case and it fixed the problem.

On my local machine, I renamed the file in Git and pushed the change.

Back on my server, I have run `git pull` and now it's saying:

> The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge
>
> Please move or remove them before you can merge

And it lists the file I renamed. I can understand why it's doing this, but I am happy for it to overwrite the file.

What do I need to run so I can finish my `git pull`?

Thanks

What can I do so the git pull

Comment: Assuming that the server files are not actively being worked on and you want to forcibly reset it to the latest master, [you do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8888015/1188035). What I imagine you did was make the changes locally on both environments, committed the one environment, and tried to pull onto the other.

Comment: There's a few minor changes I wouldn't mind keeping (just a few things commented out on the production server) so I wouldn't like to do a hard reset unless it's essential. Ideally I'd just like to know how I can force the git pull to overwrite that one untracked file. Cheers

Comment: Try `git checkout -- path/to/that/one/untracked/file` and then do a `git pull`

Comment: It says it "did not match any file(s) known to git".

Comment: Ah, because you didn't track the filename change in git on the server. Assuming the files are the exact same between your server and the already-committed local repo, try `git add path/to/that/one/untracked/file`, `git commit -m "Fixing conflict"`, `git pull`, then `git push` to get everything back in sync. I'd say delete the file and just do a simple `git pull` but I'm guessing you need it to be in place for uptime.

Comment: No problem! I've added an answer with an explanation for you to accept if it's solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summate what happened:

1. You performed something like `mv somename someName` on the server (which is essentially another local repo)

This caused git to see that `somename` was deleted and also found that `someName` was a new untracked file.

2. You performed `git mv somename someName` on your local repo

Git correctly tracks this as a file rename and handles it appropriately. Other repos pulling this change would rename the file in question appropriately with no issues.

3. You did `git commit` and `git push` from your local repo to remote
4. You tried to `git pull` onto your server from the remote repo

This didn't work because in git's eyes, you could have made an entirely new `someName` file, which would get clobbered by the newest remote repo's version of `someName` if git wasn't awesome and prevented bad things from happening.

The proper steps to take action would have been:

1. Perform `git mv somename someName` on either of the local repos
2. `git commit`, `git push` on the same repo
3. `git pull` on the other local repos

and the file renaming would have worked appropriately.

To remedy the issue you're having you can:

1. Delete the untracked file (or `mv someName somename` to revert the file back to its former local glory) on your server's repo and simply do `git pull`
2. `git add someName`, `git commit -m "Fixing a conflict mistake"`, `git pull` (to recursively merge the commit from the remote repo to your server repo's commit), and then `git push`
3. Remove all of the untracked changes by [following these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888015/1188035)