# Use of origin in Git commands

Tags: git

I'm new to Git and have a question.  These two commands seem to be a [common pairing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888015):

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

If my goal is to reset a local clone to a clean state, how is this different than either of the following?

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard master
# no origin
```

Or

```
git reset --hard origin/master
# no fetch
```

It seems like fetching first isn't needed if we are going to specify the remote directly anyway.  Am I misunderstanding something?  Is this a convention with a purpose or just a tradition/habit without basis?

Why I'm asking:

I'm writing scripts for a build machine.  I want to fetch everything at one point in time, and then work from the local content for the duration of the build so there isn't a chance of changes being made part-way through a build.  It seems like I would want to fetch from the remote once and not specify `origin` in commands after that.  However, I'm having a hard time finding examples of that online, so I wasn't sure if there was something I was missing.

Comment: For future reference, `origin/master` and `master` are both **local** branches, and they are different.  The fetch is in fact needed to update the local `origin/master` branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the basics of remote branches.  Your repository looks something like this.

```
A - B - C [origin/master]
         \
          D - E [master]
```

`master` and `origin/master` are both branches, which are just labels that point at a commit.  In this case, you've made two commits to `master` since the last time you fetched.

Git doesn't talk to the network unless you tell it to. It keeps track of the last time it looked at a remote repository with a "remote branch". `origin/master` is a "remote branch". It is your local copy of the `master` branch on the remote named `origin` updated the last time `git fetch origin` or `git fetch --all` was run (or `git pull`, which does a fetch).

---

> ```
> git reset --hard origin/master
> ```

This is used to **throw out all your local work**.  This will reset the current branch and working directory to where `origin/master` is, which is `C`.  `D` and `E` will be lost.

```
A - B - C [origin/master]
         \
          D - E [master]

git reset --hard origin/master

A - B - C [origin/master]
          [master]
```

---

> ```
> git reset --hard master
> ```

This will reset your current branch and working directory back to `master`.  *If you happen to be on `master`* this will undo your uncommitted work.  But if you're on a different branch, **you just blew away your branch**.

To throw out your uncommitted changes, the safer thing to do is `git reset --hard HEAD`.  `HEAD` is a pointer to the currently checked out commit.  It will work no matter what branch you're on.  I have it aliased to `clear`.

---

> I want to fetch everything at one point in time, and then work from the local content for the duration of the build so there isn't a chance of changes being made part-way through a build.

Git does not talk to the network unless you tell it to.  There's two commands which will update your local repository, `git fetch` and `git pull` (which does a fetch).  If you don't run those, your `origin/` remote branches will not change.

If you fetch and checkout at the start of your build, you'll be fine.  If you need to reset to a clean state you can run `git reset --hard HEAD`.  You might also want to run `git clean -dxf` which will throw out any untracked or ignored files like build artifacts.

Comment: So I did misunderstand about using `origin/`, this sentence cleared it up for me:  "`origin/master` is a 'remote branch'. It is your **local** copy of the `master` branch on the remote".  I was thinking it was remote.  Thanks!