# Git "error: invalid path 'cse5441_lab1/main." (Windows)

Tags: git

I have a repository which I use from both Windows and Linux systems. Everything was working but now I have the following error on `git pull`, on the Windows system.

```
error: invalid path 'cse5441_lab1/main.'
Updating b69442e..8dad691
```

It does pull a few other files though.

`git status` shows I am 39 commits behind.

I am guessing the last `.` in `cse5441_lab1/main.` is invalid name for a file on Windows. If so, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: What do you want to achive actually? Do you want to to sync with the last commit of the origin?

Comment: I want the latest files from the repo, onto my local windows machine. @AlexisPavlidis

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to checkout the branch on a linux machine, rename the file in question, then commit and push it.

Afterwards there should be no problems any more on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to checkout just the files with valid paths, you can do (in Git Bash):

```
git clone --sparse -c core.protectNTFS=false -n <repo-URL>
git sparse-checkout add "\!<pattern1>" "\!<pattern2>"
git checkout <branch>
```

Patterns are relative to repo root and can use `*`

More info [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2777) and [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2803).

However if you actually need those files to e.g. build the project, my best bet to do this on Windows would be to use [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).

In your particular case, if you are the only repository user, you can just rename the file on your Linux system.

Answer (score -1):

The error indicates that there are some conflicts on the update.

Try using the following command: `git reset --hard origin/master`

The above git command will throw away all your staged and unstaged changes, and everything on your current local branch and make it exactly the same as `origin/master`.

*if you want to pull from different branch other than the `master` then just change the branch name from `master` to your desired branch name*

Comment: Getting similar error ```error: invalid path 'cse5441_lab1/main.'
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/master'.```

Comment: Did you try using  `Sparse checkout` ? Here is an answer that might be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702140/git-pull-invalid-windows-file-names

Comment: Note that if you are using sparse-checkout on windows, you may need to add core.protectNTFS false per https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2777