# Check out git repository that contains invalid filenames in windows

Tags: windows, git, filenames

Our git repository has until recently only been used on linux and it contains some files that have a colon `:` within their filename.  The filenames can not be changed due to internal requirements. Is it still possible to checkout this repository on a windows machine without getting an  `unable to checkout working tree` Error?

If possible, these files could be totally ignored by the User on the Windows Machine, they don't need to be modified but they just can't be deleted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git pull invalid Windows file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702140/git-pull-invalid-windows-file-names). To be precise, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33705131/12232870

Comment: No, I simply can not perform an git pull and checkout on the repo since it says "unable to checkout working tree"

Comment: git-pull and git-checkout are totally different operations. Doesn't git [sparse checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout) work for you? The linked question also refers the same issue and uses git-sparse-checkout as a way to ignore files on checkout by filename/path patterns.