# Clear local git repo, start completely fresh from remote

Tags: git

I sometimes screw up my local git repo so badly that I need to just wipe it out and start again from the latest commit on `remote`. Is there a correct way to do this with git, or should I just delete the local repo and `pull` again? I tried the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/force-git-to-overwrite-local-files-on-pull), but my local repo was still detached from `HEAD`.

Here's one example to prevent anyone from asking why I want to do this instead of fixing my mistake. I somehow ended up with a detached `HEAD`, and other SO posts indicate it's a PITA to fix. My latest commit on `remote` is fine, I've only changed one file, so I saved my changes and just want to start fresh instead of trying to fix the detached `HEAD`.

Comment: after few commits or only with some local change?

Comment: @rajuGT I don't need to save anything local. It can all be wiped out and I'll just pull the latest commit info from `remote`.

Comment: Detached HEAD isn't that hard to fix...`git checkout <branch>` and you're pretty well sorted, provided you haven't *really* gone off the reservation and made commits in detached HEAD mode...

Comment: @Makoto I made no commits, but checking out was what detached HEAD in the first place.

Comment: If you checked out a SHA or a tag, sure, that's exactly what happens.  If you check out a branch, Git knows where it needs to go in the hierarchy so there's no detaching of HEAD.

Comment: @Makoto is right, a "detached HEAD" is really quite trivial and normal.  It's sometimes portrayed as scary and difficult, I think mainly to make sure people don't do a bunch of work in that mode and then not know how to retain the work.  But ultimately all it means is that you're not on any branch.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "the latest commit on remote" you mean on `origin/master`, you can easily reset to that state with the following command:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Or you can simply reset all local changes since the last local commit by doing:

```
git reset --hard
```

Additionally, you may want to experiment with the `git clean` command to clear away any untracked local files. `git clean` won't undo your changes, you need `git reset --hard` for that.