# Cannot switch branches

Tags: git, github

I'm not at all a git expert and my local git repo is in a bad way.
I have got two branches master and Deriche. I work now on local branch  Deriche branch and I want to switch master

```
$ git checkout master 
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        modules/ximgproc/src/deriche_filter.cpp Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches. Aborting
```

then

```
$ git stash 
Saved working directory and index state WIP on Deriche: 64025bc Add files via upload 
HEAD is now at 64025bc Add files via upload
```

then again

```
$ git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        modules/ximgproc/src/deriche_filter.cpp
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Then git diff results are :

```
$git diff
diff --git a/modules/ximgproc/src/deriche_filter.cpp b/modules/ximgproc/src/deriche_filter.cpp
index 0e45ffb..58d20ca 100644
--- a/modules/ximgproc/src/deriche_filter.cpp
+++ b/modules/ximgproc/src/deriche_filter.cpp
@@ -1,464 +1,464 @@
-<U+FEFF>#include "precomp.hpp"
-#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
......
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/force-git-to-overwrite-local-files-on-pull) without any success.

Thanks you in advance for your help

Comment: What does `git diff` show?

Comment: I have update question Thanks you for your interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something to do with that `<U+FEFF>` character. (It is a textual representation of Unicode character [Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FEFF/index.htm).)

That being said, if `git stash` and `git reset --hard` do not work, try

```
git checkout HEAD~0
git add modules/ximgproc/src/deriche_filter.cpp
git commit -m Trash
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. I will have to investigate origin of this chararcter