# Git error when pulling to cloudways (Laravel 4 app)

Tags: php, git, laravel, cloudways

My first deployment, so I installed Laravel 4 on cloudways , I did my first pull, the app was working, now when I did a small change to my BitBucket repository and than pull again to cloudways it gave me the following error:

```
Failed
Error doing git pull: ('Auto-merging bootstrap/start.php\nCONFLICT (add/add):  
Merge conflict in bootstrap/start.php\nAuto-merging app/routes.php\nCONFLICT 
(add/add): Merge conflict in app/routes.php\nAuto-merging 
app/config/local/database.php\nCONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in 
app/config/local/database.php\nAuto-merging app/config/database.php\nCONFLICT 
(add/add): Merge conflict in app/config/database.php\nAuto-merging 
app/config/app.php\nCONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in 
app/config/app.php\nAutomatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the 
result.\n', 'From bitbucket.org:FatCowSoftware/pgtest\n * branch master -> 
FETCH_HEAD\n')
```

Comment: If you open those files, you will see where the conflicts were.  All you should need to do is fix them and make another commit with your changes.

Comment: but what is a conflict? shouldn't git override old files with new?

Comment: there is a change I did to those files but, that was my intend, I want to make changes to my remote app

Comment: If you are making changes remotely, you should do a pull before you start making changes.  Then after the changes are done, do a commit.  Git is trying to save you from overwriting your files.  If you just want to replace the files you are working on with whatever is in your git repository, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/force-git-to-overwrite-local-files-on-pull

Comment: @Mikail Can you list down precisely the steps you did to get this error?

Comment: You need to merge you branch in master and then create a new commit. After that pull the code on Cloudways. you can follow the guide to resolve conflicts in code here: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/manage-branches-and-resolve-conflicts-git/