# Non-existent ':get' file in detected by Git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, git

I had this error with git `the following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge: :get` when trying to pull updates from `origin`.

I had no idea where this `:get` file is so I ignored it and went ahead to do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888015/3893713, which finally updated by the branch that was causing the problem to match with the one at `origin`.

However I still have this file as an unstaged file (checked with `git status`), but I don't think it even exists. I can't see it in Windows explorer even with 'show hidden files' enabled. Tried using `del` in cmd but to no avail.

EDIT: Screenshot
[image: Screenshot of Git Output]

Comment: provide output of `git status`

Comment: For what it's worth, Windows forbids ASCII colon `:` in file names: it's the drive-letter separator (as in `C:\path\to\file`, for instance). So `:get` is simply impossible. There are some Unicode characters that *resemble* colons, but it seems likely that your Windows Git binary has something broken in it. I don't "do" Windows, though, so it may not be Git's fault at all, but rather something else wrong with your Windows system (well, "something wrong" other than "it's Windows" :) ).