# git pull says local master branch is up-to-date with origin master branch; it isn't

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to get my local master branch to resemble `origin/master`.
In my local `develop` branch I deleted `c.py` and `d.py`, which I then pushed to `origin/develop` and merged into `origin/master`. I then ran `git checkout master` and `git pull origin master` and now I'm getting an "Everything up to date" message.

Current file discrepancies are as follows:

#### Local Master

```
 root_directory/
    index.py
    classes/
        __init__.py
        a.py
        b.py
        c.py
        d.py
```

#### Origin/master

```
 root_directory/
    index.py
    classes/
        __init__.py
        a.py
        b.py
```

When I run `git pull origin master` I get the following message:

```
From https://github.com/username/repo
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

One answer to another SO question I found recommended using `git pull --rebase`. This is the the message I get from that:

```
Current branch master is up to date.
```

And finally, when I run `git status` I receive:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

What am I doing wrong here? What can I do to make my local master branch *actually* resemble `origin/master`?

Comment: try git reset --soft and then try to pull

Comment: Would a `git clean -fdn` (`-n` for dry-run) report it would delete `c.py` and `d.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Thank you guys for the response, but after more searching (with fresh eyes) I got it to work. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-to-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files), and tried the suggested fix:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Then I received the message:

> HEAD is now at 5d54662 Merge pull request #1 from GitHubUser/develop

Upon looking in the `classes` directory it now reflects the expected directory contents:

```
  root_directory/
      index.py
      classes/
          __init__.py
          a.py
          b.py
```

#### Again, thank you two for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

How have you merged `origin/develop` with `origin/master`, using GUI, pull request then merge? If not then, you can merge locally then push to remote.

```
$ git checkout develop                # checkout develop 
$ git push origin develop             # push changes to remote develop

$ git checkout master                 # checkout master
$ git pull origin master              # sync with origin/master
$ git pull origin develop             # merge develop into master
$ git push origin master              # push master to remote
```

Comment: I merged origin/develop into origin/master via a Pull Request on GitHub. When I tried your suggestions I received "Already up-to-date" and "Everything up-to-date".

Comment: ok. Do you see your `origin/develop` changes in `origin/master` GitHub? If yes, then try `git fetch`, then `git reset origin/master` locally.

Answer (score 0):

> which I then pushed to origin/develop and merged into origin/master

How did you merge it to `origin/master`?

A merge is a *local* operation: you would need to merge `develop` to `master` locally, then push `master`, before another repo could pull from `origin master` and find an altered content.

```
git checkout master
git merge develop
git push
```

Comment: I merged origin/develop into origin/master via a Pull Request on GitHub. Trying your suggestions I received the same messages that I posted in the comment to sajib kahns answer.