# Updating pull request from upstream remote fork

Tags: git, github

So I'm currently reviewing a pull request from an upstream repo that I forked, and created a local branch to fetch the pull request via `git fetch upstream pull/869/head:readme`. However, there have been some recent commits made to that pull request since I created the branch. How do I update the pull request branch to incorporate the new commits? Pull requests aren't visible in the same way that would allow me to otherwise do a `git fetch upstream` and `git merge upstream/master`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force "git pull" to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files)

Comment: Is there a way to directly access pull request branches? I see upstream/master or upstream/staging, not the pull request branches on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
git config --add remote.upstream.fetch "+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/upstream/pr/*"
```

See more at "[prm.md](https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247)". The default refspec (`+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*`) does not fetch pull request

Then a `fetch upstream` would allow you to see

```
upstream/pr/189
```

And you can rebase (not merge) your own branch of top of it.

```
git rebase upstream/pr/189
```

Comment: This results in a `fetch` refspec that looks like `fetch = fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/upstream/pr/*`

Comment: @VigneshSankaran sorry, I forgot the `--add`  option, in order to keep the default refspec. Restore it with `git config --add remote.upstream.fetch "fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*"`.