# Overwriting my local changes in response to GIT error: “The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge”

Tags: git, command-line

In other solutions for GIT error: "The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge" -- many solutions involve git stash and then git stash pop, but how would I just overwrite my local changes with the git pull I'm doing. How would that be done?

I don't care for my local changes if it gets overwritten. I have many files that are not in conflict to this error, so I can't just remove these files via git clean neither.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force "git pull" to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files)

Answer (score 0):

This was the error for me:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    img/theme/button.png
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

I just did what the message says: `"Please move or remove them before you merge."`

I removed `button.png` and then tried `git pull ...` again. This time everything worked correctly and without problems. What was happening in my case is that my `git pull ...` included a commit that had this `img/theme/button.png` image. Then the image already existed and it would be overwritten. As a result of that, I was getting that error message. But it was fixed for me as I mentioned by removing the file and then pulling again.