# Git update local files with remote branch

Tags: git

I have checkout branch and have made some changes. I want to overwrite the changes with the changes from same remote branch. I don't want to save the local changes made.

I tried git pull : It says "Already up to date" . But my local changes are still there.

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force "git pull" to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files)

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the HEAD of the git repository to the one of your remote branch.

```
git reset --hard @{u}
```

`@{u}` points to the last commit on the remote branch. `--hard` discard all changes made.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset hard using following command it will discard your changes and update with latest changes:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>
```