# cant git pull because of .gitignore untracked

Tags: git, gitignore, pull

After performing:
`git pull origin master`

I get the following:

```
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
.gitignore
Please move or remove them before you merge.

Aborting
```

How can I continue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force "git pull" to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pull+error%3A+The+following+untracked+working+tree+files+would+be+overwritten+by+merge

Answer (score 1):

The output telling you that you have uncommitted changes.

You can do one of the following:

To `add & commit` your changes:

```
# Add and commit changes
git add . && git commit -m"Message"
```

To discard changes:

```
# discard your changes
git checkout -- .gitignore
```