# How to undo a reset after push?

Tags: git, git-reset

I wanted to revert a pushed commit and because of lack of knowledge I did

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1 
git push -f
```

Now , after this , people who already had pulled the commit which i reset , they are not able to go back . 
`git pull` does not take them 1 commit back .

How do I solve this mess now ? Any suggestions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files

Comment: they should do hard reset too: `git reset --hard HEAD`, then pull, but they will lost their local changes

Comment: Can `git stash` backup their work before they reset?

Comment: @simbo1905 Yes, and it's even maybe a better solution than committing on the branch, since it might soon be reset. And I'd even advocate for a branch backup before the reset, just in case...

Comment: You can also go back to their version and use `git revert`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer** : In all cases, before doing anything, be sure to :

- discuss it in details with your team so that you all agree on a plan
- everyone saves/commits their local changes before reseting anything, either with `git stash` like hinted at by simbo1905 in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55344785/how-to-undo-a-reset-after-push#comment97414975_55344785), or by commiting on the branch then backing it up with

  `git branch backup-branch old-branch`

---

Now in short, 2 approaches, depending on the specifics of your project and the nature of the changes you just pushed :

**1) either everyone goes for *your* version**

Every other user updates his/her local branch with

```
git fetch
git reset --hard <remoteName>/<branchName>
```

**2) or *their* version is to be kept**

In this case, one of the other users with the old ref for this branch* does a `git push -f <remoteName> <branchName>`, and *you* are to do the above operations to sync back with them.

* *(in case noone can do that for any reason, you could also recover the ref locally from the branch's [`reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) and push it again to remote with force, it's just often quicker to push it from the repo of someone with the old ref)*