# How can i update a live laravel project using git

Tags: laravel, git, gitlab

I have uploaded a fresh laravel project on live server using git (gitlab), now i'm using git pull the new updates on live server after i pushed from local and it says the update was completed with success but nothing changes. my local project only has the update, the live project don't. what can be the problem and how can i fix it

Comment: in your server type 'git log' to see list of your commits. See if last commit message in server is the same with your last commit on local.

Answer (score 1):

It could just be aggressive caching. What are you changing?

Try:

```sh
$ php artisan cache:clear
$ php artisan view:clear
$ php artisan config:clear
$ php artisan route:clear
```

Then try viewing your site in a Private/Incognito tab.

Beyond that, you could try resetting to the current head in Github.

If that doesn't work, check the github repo for the updated code (using web interface).

`git reset --hard origin/master`

OR If you are on some other branch:

`git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>`

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888015/1848660

Answer (score 0):

I had activated cloudflare and it was messing up with my updates. thank you

Comment: You should pick your own answer as a solution to close this question :)