# how to pull from a branch ignoring all the conflicts from the master

Tags: git

After `git pull origin branch-name` on local master branch, I got an error which says 'Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.' as the branch is several commits ahead and several behind the master. If I want to takes all changes from the remote branch and ignore conflicts, where should I do?

I tried `git merge --strategy-option theirs` which returns error 'error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force "git pull" to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files)

Comment: If you didn’t have any uncommitted changes before pulling, you can `git reset --hard HEAD` and then do the merge.

Comment: I did that, and still shows 'fix conflict and commit the result'. I have no local changes except a master that differs from the branch

Comment: Sorry, `git merge --abort`, actually.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Generally, if you want to blow away any local changes and just update to the remote master branch, this would work:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
```

If you have local changes that you want to clean, you might have to do the following first:

```
git reset --hard
git clean -df
```

Comment: thanks. this worked. what if I want to take a certain remote branch (non-master) and compare it with current master to check the changes?

Comment: Depending on how you want to see those changes, you could do git log HEAD..<remote branch> or git diff HEAD..<remote branch>