# Deleted Files/Folders persisting on branch change Git

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have two branches, master, feature/...

Feature is cut from master and the ask is to clean up the project.  Where I am deleting files and directories.  Finish my work, `git add .`, `git commit -m 'updated'`, `git push`.  All said and done, I see the updates in the remote origin.  I go back to master, as expected the code reappears that I deleted.

Problem: 
I switch back to my feature branch where I deleted files/folders but the files/folders that I deleted are still there.  Even though I can see clearly that the files were deleted on the remote origin branch.

This seems to be the best resolution that I've found, [How do I force "git pull" to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files)

However, it doesn't truly answer my question as to why is this happening?  Why do I have to do all this refreshing when you'd think Git would just update this on the branch switch?

Comment: Are you talking about files that are not tracked by git?

Comment: They aren't the "untracked files".  They are just leftover from switching the branches from master to the feature.  I can see the deleted files on the remote and if I delete the files/folders manual nothing changes to my git status.

Comment: Are you able to replicate this in a new repo?

Comment: I had the same ask on two different repos with the same action, yes.

Comment: It's a private work repo otherwise I'd share.

Comment: Try doing a `git rm` on a coupe of the files you want to remove.

Comment: There is nothing to remove from the remote, so git rm is no different, in that it still doesn't answer my question to why the files/folders persist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files that are *tracked* by Git will be removed by Git when switching from a commit in which they exist (and hence are tracked<sup>1</sup>) to a commit in which they do not exist (and hence are not tracked).  Having been removed by switching from the commit in which those files existed and were tracked, to a commit in which they do not exist and are not tracked, they are not in the work-tree and are not untracked files.

Should you somehow—by *any* means—switch from a commit in which a file is tracked, to a commit in which it is not, and therefore remove the copy of the file from the index<sup>2</sup> so that it is untracked, without also removing the copy of the file from your work-tree,<sup>3</sup> that file is now *untracked* and therefore Git *won't* remove it.  There are multiple ways to achieve this, including running `git rm --cached`, which removes a copy of a file from the index without touching the copy of the file in your work-tree.

Git does little, and cares nothing, about *folders:* folders are the province, obsession, and problem of your *computer system*, not of Git.  All Git cares about are *files*, which have names that for some reason, your computer insists on breaking up into folder-y pieces ending with a file-y piece: `dir/sub/file.ext`, which is a *file* in Git's eyes, is not a file on your computer: it is a folder (or directory) named `dir` containing a folder named `sub` containing a file named `file.ext`.  Git does its best to accommodate your operating system's obsession with "folders" by *creating* `dir/` so that it can *create* `dir/sub/` so that it can create `dir/sub/file.ext`—the file it cares about—on demand.  When Git is *cleaning out* a bunch of files such as `dir/sub/file1.ext` through `dir/sub/fileN.ext`, if it has cleaned out the *last* file, it will remove `dir/sub/` as well.  But it cannot do that if *any* file, including an untracked one, remains in that directory, so in that case, it won't ... and having removed all the `dir/sub/*` files—remember, to Git, these are just *files*, there's no folder-ing involved here—that it was tracking, Git now has no idea that `dir/sub/` even exists any more.  That's now *your* problem; if you remove the last of the untracked files from there, it's up to you to remove the directory too.

I have, over the decades, seen various corner cases where Git *doesn't* remove empty folders / directories despite having just cleaned them out while updating the index.  These have decreased over time: it's *much* rarer now than it was back in 2005 (to the extent that I have not personally seen it in some years now).  If you can find a *repeatable* sequence that leaves these behind, that does not involve operator error (untracked files), this is a bug, and you can file a bug report with the Git folks.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>A Git file is *tracked* if and only if it is in the index.  That's all there is to this: the presence of a file in the index means the file is tracked.  The absence of a file in the index means that the file is not tracked.

To examine the index contents—note that this is quite long and not meant for everyday use by users—run `git ls-files --stage`.  This thing—the entity that Git calls the *index*—is a central and key concept; you *must* understand how Git uses it, at least to some degree, to use Git effectively.  Unfortunately, many Git tutorials try to hide it.  Git itself doesn't show it very well: `git ls-files --stage` is not friendly at all.

The index is also known as the *staging area*, and (rarely these days) the *cache*.  All three names refer to the same thing, although some commands (e.g., `git apply`) use `--cached` and `--index` in different ways.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, the "copies" of files in the index are actually references to Git's internal *blob objects*.  See the `git ls-files --stage` output from footnote 1: each file entry in the index consists of a *mode*, a *blob hash ID*, a *staging slot number*—usually zero—and a *name*.  (The index also contains cache data, hence one of its three alternate names.)

<sup>3</sup>The copies of files in your work-tree are yours to play with.  That is *why* this is your work-tree: it is where you do your work.  Git does not use these files to make the *next* commit; it uses instead the copies / references that are in the index.  It's the *index* that matters when making new commits, and `git checkout` first extracts a checked-out commit *to* the index, before un-freezing and de-compressing and generally un-Git-ifying your files so that you can access them in your work-tree.

This is also why you have to `git add` files all the time: `git add` means *copy the file back into the index*, i.e., replace the frozen-format blob object with a new one made from whatever is in the work-tree now.  Note that `git add` will in fact *remove* a file from the index, if the file is *not* in the work-tree, so in that sense, it's really *make the index copy match the work-tree copy*, even if that means *remove the file*.

<sup>4</sup>If you're using an ancient version of Git, upgrade before filing.  If `git --version` prints anything older than about 2.17, that's pretty ancient.  The current version is 2.25.1.

Comment: Thank you very well explained.  I am restructuring a repo that has several projects underneath it.  We are breaking those projects out into the "micro" architecture.  Very helpful