# fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories; overwrite history

Tags: git

I have the following problem

```
git pull
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

git pull --allow-unrelated-histories
^@Auto-merging README.md
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in README.md
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

git pull
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

Thus please no `--allow-unrelated-histories` suggestions. Also, I don't want to merge (or rebase?) anything; the content of remote and locale repo are basically the same.
However, `git log` shows me a completely wrong history, which comes from a submodule.
Probably, I somehow screw it up.

Can I some overwrite the locale history with the remote history?

(The local repo has some untracked files, which I want to keep; otherwise I would just clone the remote repo again.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overwrite local history with remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67863536/how-to-overwrite-local-history-with-remote)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67863703/11769765:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/main
```

What did **not** work:

- `git reset --hard`
- `git reset --hard origin/master`

Useful commands for inspecting/setting the right repo: `git log`, `git remote show origin`, `git remote set-url origin ssh://git@...`.