# How do I globally configure Git so that pulls overwrite the local files?

Tags: git

I understand there are [various strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files) for forcing Git to completely overwrite the local files from a remote on a per invocation basis, but is there a way to configure get (with `git config`) so that `git pull` overwrites local files every time?

Answer (score 1):

The best I can recommend is setting an *alias*.

That's what I use:

```
# ~/.config/git/config

[alias]
    pf = !"git fetch --all; git reset --hard HEAD; git merge @{u}"
```

The above alias will discard all local changes. If you just want a `pull --force`:

```
# ~/.config/git/config

[alias]
   pf = pull --force --no-rebase
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  Or, in other words:

> is there a way to configure gtt (with `git config`) so that `git pull` overwrites local files every time?

No.

It's worth noting two things here:

1. `git pull` is a *convenience command* that runs two more-basic Git commands for you.
2. The *second* command that `git pull` runs is **never** an *overwrite files* command.  The first command is an "obtain commits" command, which is `git fetch`.  The second command is a "combine obtained commits with current commits somehow" command.  The second command is configurable; the first one is not; but no matter which second command you choose, it doesn't mean *overwrite*.

What this means is that if you want files overwritten, *do not use `git pull`.*

Note that Git is not really about *files* anyway.  What Git is all about is *commits*.  If you aren't interested in using and working with commits (e.g., if you're interested in doing a server deployment), you probably should not be using Git at all here (though many people do use Git as a poor-man's deployment system: it can be pressed into service as one, just as a screwdriver can be used as a chisel, if you need a chisel and all you have is a screwdriver).

Answer (score -3):

This is done via

$ git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master

This sets the local branch to track to the upstream remote branch. Git pull should then automatically fetch and merge the branch to your local repo files.

Comment: How does this answer OP question?