# How to pull the branch of remote repo to cover the changes in the local repo

Tags: git, github

Git Structure:

```
1. Local repo:
    (1) main
    (2) test_branch

2. Remote repo:
    (1) main
    (2) test_branch
```

For some reasons, some contents in test_branch in the local repo are messed up, so I want to pull the test_branch in the remote repo to the test_branch in the local repo to recover the original structure.

Tried:

```
git checkout test_branch

git pull origin test_branch
```

But it didn't work.

Also dig other threads :

[Git: How do I force "git pull" to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/git-how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files)

Tried:

```
git fetch --all

git branch backup-test_branch

git reset --hard origin/test_branch
```

But it also didn't work.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: `git fetch --all` might not work as you expect. Try `git branch backup-master;git fetch origin test_branch;git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always delete your local branch and recover from the remote, try the following:

```
git checkout main

git branch -D test_branch

git checkout test_branch
```

To explain what it's doing, it is changing the current branch to `main`, deleting the local copy of the `test_branch` and then changing back to the `test_branch` branch, but now synchronized with the remote one.

Comment: After deleting test_branch, shouldn't it add -b as checkout test_branch?

Comment: @Sky If you add the `-b` flag then you're going to create a new branch, if you don't then you're going to create a copy of the remote `test_branch`. That happens because you have already fetched from your remote and you have a local reference to a remote branch.

Comment: IIUC, do you mean that `git checkout test_branch` will create a copy of the remote `test_branch`? As my understanding, copying a remote repository generally uses the command such as `git fetch` or `git pull`, but here I don't see such command in the above three commands. That's why I am confused.

Comment: @Sky You're right, git checkout wont create a copy, but It will use the already created copy from a previous `git pull` or `git fetch`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!