# I've checked out a past commit and made some chages, how do I overwrite local changes in the commit in one command?

Tags: git

I've seen [How do I force "git pull" to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files) but `git fetch -all; git reset --hard origin/master` will reverts to the latest commit.

My question is :

I checked out into a previous commit, then I made some modifications to the local files. Now, I want to revert all the local changes but stay in that commit. What is the command ?

(Of course I know I can do 'git checkout' for all the modified files but there should be a couple of commands).

Comment: You mean `git reset --hard HEAD`? It will undo everything that isn't in the currently checked out commit.

Comment: Ah! that was it. (I realized how to use HEAD now..). If you make your comment as an aswer, I can selete it. Thank you!

Comment: No thanks, this seems trivial, almost tautological. As you rightly imply, it is simply an expression of what "HEAD" means. Note that you could omit saying `HEAD` here, as it is implicit; I usually just say `git reset --hard` plain and simple.

Comment: One more solution is `git restore .`, or probably `git checkout .` will do the same

Comment: Side note: you almost never want to use `git fetch --all` (which has two dashes, not one).